# How did moving calculations from run-time to compile-time make my code slower?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, c++20, consteval

I'm writing a function to calculate the fast Fourier transform using the Stockham FFT algorithm and discovered that all of the "twiddle factors" for the calculation can be pre-calculated at compile time if the length of the FFT is a power of two.

In FFT calculations the twiddle factor calculations usually take up a large portion of the overall time so in theory doing this should result in a drastic improvement in the performance of the algorithm.

I spent all day yesterday reimplementing my algorithm on a new compiler (gcc 10) so I could use the C++20 `consteval` feature to pre-calculate all of the twiddle factors at compile time. I was successfully able to do it, but in the end the code that pre-calculates all of the twiddle factors at compile time actually runs slower!

Here is the code that performs all of the calculations at runtime:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<complex<double>> StockhamFFT(const vector<complex<double>>& x);

constexpr bool IsPowerOf2(const size_t value)
{
    return value && (!(value & (value - 1)));
}

vector<complex<double>> FFT(const vector<double>& x)
{
    const auto N = x.size();
    assert(IsPowerOf2(x.size()));
    const auto NOver2 = N/2;

    vector<complex<double>> x_p(N);
    transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x_p.begin(), [](const double value) {
        return complex<double>(value);
        });

    return StockhamFFT(x_p);
}

// C++ implementation of the Stockam FFT algorithm
static vector<complex<double>> StockhamFFT(const vector<complex<double>>& x)
{
    const auto N = x.size();
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));
    const auto NOver2 = N/2;

    // Pre-calculate the twiddle factors (at runtime)
    vector<complex<double>> W(NOver2);
    const auto omega = 2.0 * M_PI / N;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < NOver2; ++n)
    {
        W[n] = complex{ cos(-omega * n), sin(-omega * n) };
    }

    // The Stockham algorithm requires one vector for input/output data and
    // another as a temporary workspace
    vector<complex<double>> a(x);
    vector<complex<double>> b(N);

    // Set the spacing between twiddle factors used at the first stage
    size_t WStride = N/2;

    // Loop through each stage of the FFT
    for (size_t stride = 1; stride < N; stride *= 2)
    {
        // Loop through the individual FFTs of each stage
        for (size_t m = 0; m < NOver2; m += stride)
        {
            const auto mTimes2 = m*2;

            // Perform each individual FFT
            for (size_t n = 0; n < stride; ++n)
            {
                // Calculate the input indexes
                const auto aIndex1 = n + m;
                const auto aIndex2 = aIndex1 + NOver2;

                // Calculate the output indexes
                const auto bIndex1 = n + mTimes2;
                const auto bIndex2 = bIndex1 + stride;

                // Perform the FFT
                const auto tmp1 = a[aIndex1];
                const auto tmp2 = W[n*WStride]*a[aIndex2];

                // Sum the results
                b[bIndex1] = tmp1 + tmp2;
                b[bIndex2] = tmp1 - tmp2; // (>*.*)> symmetry! <(*.*<)
            }
        }

        // Spacing between twiddle factors is half for the next stage
        WStride /= 2;

        // Swap the data (output of this stage is input of the next)
        a.swap(b);
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    size_t N = pow(2, 18);
    vector<double> x(N);

    int f_s = 1000;
    double t_s = 1.0 / f_s;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        x[n] = sin(2 * M_PI * 100 * n * t_s);
    }

    auto sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto X = FFT(x);
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        sum += duration.count();
    }
    auto average = sum / 100;

    std::cout << "duration " << average << " microseconds." << std::endl;
}
```

With this as a starting point I was able to extract out the twiddle factor calculations from the `StockhamFFT` function and perform them at compile-time using a `consteval` function. This is what the code looks like after:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<complex<double>> StockhamFFT(const vector<complex<double>>& x);

constexpr bool IsPowerOf2(const size_t value)
{
    return value && (!(value & (value - 1)));
}

// Evaluates FFT twiddle factors at compile time!
template <size_t N>
static consteval array<complex<double>, N/2> CalculateTwiddleFactors()
{
    static_assert(IsPowerOf2(N), "N must be a power of 2.");

    array<complex<double>, N/2> W;
    const auto omega = 2.0*M_PI/N;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N/2; ++n)
    {
        W[n] = complex{cos(-omega*n), sin(-omega*n)};
    }

    return W;
}

// Calculate the twiddle factors (>*O*)> AT COMPILE TIME <(*O*<)
constexpr auto W = CalculateTwiddleFactors<static_cast<size_t>(pow(2,18))>();

vector<complex<double>> FFT(const vector<double>& x)
{
    const auto N = x.size();
    assert(IsPowerOf2(x.size()));
    const auto NOver2 = N/2;

    vector<complex<double>> x_p(N);
    transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x_p.begin(), [](const double value) {
        return complex<double>(value);
        });

    return StockhamFFT(x_p);
}

// C++ implementation of the Stockam FFT algorithm
static vector<complex<double>> StockhamFFT(const vector<complex<double>>& x)
{
    const auto N = x.size();
    assert(IsPowerOf2(N));
    const auto NOver2 = N/2;

    //***********************************************************************
    // Twiddle factors are already calculated at compile time!!!
    //***********************************************************************

    // The Stockham algorithm requires one vector for input/output data and
    // another as a temporary workspace
    vector<complex<double>> a(x);
    vector<complex<double>> b(N);

    // Set the spacing between twiddle factors used at the first stage
    size_t WStride = N/2;

    // Loop through each stage of the FFT
    for (size_t stride = 1; stride < N; stride *= 2)
    {
        // Loop through the individual FFTs of each stage
        for (size_t m = 0; m < NOver2; m += stride)
        {
            const auto mTimes2 = m*2;

            // Perform each individual FFT
            for (size_t n = 0; n < stride; ++n)
            {
                // Calculate the input indexes
                const auto aIndex1 = n + m;
                const auto aIndex2 = aIndex1 + NOver2;

                // Calculate the output indexes
                const auto bIndex1 = n + mTimes2;
                const auto bIndex2 = bIndex1 + stride;

                // Perform the FFT
                const auto tmp1 = a[aIndex1];
                const auto tmp2 = W[n*WStride]*a[aIndex2];

                // Sum the results
                b[bIndex1] = tmp1 + tmp2;
                b[bIndex2] = tmp1 - tmp2; // (>*.*)> symmetry! <(*.*<)
            }
        }

        // Spacing between twiddle factors is half for the next stage
        WStride /= 2;

        // Swap the data (output of this stage is input of the next)
        a.swap(b);
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    size_t N = pow(2, 18);
    vector<double> x(N);

    int f_s = 1000;
    double t_s = 1.0 / f_s;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        x[n] = sin(2 * M_PI * 100 * n * t_s);
    }

    auto sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto X = FFT(x);
        auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
        sum += duration.count();
    }
    auto average = sum / 100;

    std::cout << "duration " << average << " microseconds." << std::endl;
}
```

Both versions were compiled on Ubuntu 19.10 with gcc 10.0.1:

```
g++ -std=c++2a -o main main.cpp
```

*Note that the gcc compiler is specifically required because it is the only compiler that supports `constexpr` versions of `sin` and `cos`*

The "run-time" example yields the following:

> duration 292854 microseconds.

The "compile-time" example yields the following:

> duration 295230 microseconds.

The compile-time version did take notably longer to compile, but still somehow takes longer to run even though most of the calculations are done before the program even begins! How is this possible? Am I missing something critical here?

Comment: Did you compile with optimization on (`-O2`)?

Comment: I just gave it a try and when I use `-O2` the compile-time version runs a bit faster than the runtime one. (about 30000 microseconds for run-time, 26000 for compile-time). Even with that being the case it still makes no logical sense that it would be slower even unoptimized!

Comment: And realistically even with optimization I would expect a much more significant improvement from precalculating all of the twiddle factors.

Comment: Those 26 milliseconds could be heap allocation (as part of `std::vector`).

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" ~Knuth. In other words, don't spend time optimising something unless you've profiled it and know it's actually causing a bottleneck. Though it would be interesting to know the answer...

Comment: @LordAro yeah I get that, but I'm literally just taking a large chunk of the calculation that does a lot of `sin` and `cos` computations that are expensive completely out of the algorithm and doing it at compile time. The rest of the algorithm is completely untouched. It just makes no logical sense that it wouldn't provide a significant improvement (even completely unoptimized).

Comment: Unoptimised code is often slow in surprising ways, the complier makes very little effort to make your code fast with optimisations turned off, use unoptimised code for debugging only, never for performance measurements

Comment: Okay, well at this point unless I find out more I'm going to go back to the run-time calculated version since the improvement even optimized is not very impressive. That way I'm not tied to `gcc` as my compiler and it'll be easier to keep my code cross-platform compatible.

Comment: @rustyx, I literally *just* realized you meant that the vast majority of the runtime may be due to the fact that I allocate memory on the heap at all. If that's the case, I didn't realize heap allocation could be that expensive! I'll give it a try with a fixed sized array and see if I get a more consistent benchmark.